# Detox - Possible to Force Fail Test?

Tags: react-native, detox

Is there a way to force a test to fail in Detox? I haven't found anything in the documentation that says this can be the case. I am comparing two IDs that are hidden in an element and screen of my app and if they don't match, I want to fail the test.

```
if (element.id === screen.id) {
    do
}
else {
    *fail test*
}

it(`should invite User`, async () => {}
```

Or is it as easy as just throwing an error? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Detox itself delegates test logic to a [test runner](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/introduction/getting-started#set-up-a-test-runner).

> Detox delegates the actual JavaScript test-code execution to a dedicated test-runner. It supports the popular Jest and Mocha out of the box.

If you are using `jest` as the underlying `test runner`, you could just use its `fail` method as follows.

```js
if (element.id === screen.id) {
    do
}
else {
    fail('test fails');
}
```

In `mocha` you could use the following function.

```js
assert.fail("actual", "expected", "Error message");
```

We could also abuse the [detox high level api](https://wix.github.io/Detox/docs/api/expect) to achieve the same (but less readable).

```js
await waitFor(element(by.id(notVisible.id))).toBeVisible().withTimeout(5);
```